# How to Suppress Windows Security Alert when Launching Java Program via CMD?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, command-line, windows-firewall

I'm launching a program with administrative privileges in `Java` using the `CMD`:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, new File(processDir));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

This causes the Windows Security Alert dialog to appear:

[image]

I would like to suppress the dialog from appearing as this would require manual input for a program that is suppose to be fully automated.

**1)** Is it possible to execute a specific command in a way that prevents the dialog from appearing for that command?

**2)** If not, is it possible to programmatically disable the dialog from ever appearing?

Presumably, I could completely disable `Windows Defender Firewall` but this isn't ideal.

I'm using `Java + Windows 10`.

Thanks

Comment: To whoever voted to close the question: This question is specifically how to programmatically launch a program (in Java) while bypassing Windows Defender Firewall dialog. Can you explain why you voted to close this question?

Comment: "Configure and manage Microsoft Defender Antivirus with the mpcmdrun.exe command-line tool" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/command-line-arguments-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide